# search and replace thousands of lines php

Tags: php

I am very new to using preg_replace and such so please bear with me.

I have few hundreds line that contains this line

```
<strong>[*<a title="*" name="*"></a>]</strong><br /> Lorem ipsum
```

* on above code denotes that number such as 1,2,3

What i want to achieve is that

```
*. Lorem Ipsum

Example, 1. Lorem ipsum, 2. Lorem ipsum
```

What would be the best way to achieve it? Thanks.

sample text

```
<strong>[1<a title="1" name="1"></a>]</strong><br /> Lorem ipsum 12345<br /> <strong>[2<a title="2" name="2"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdasd<br /> <strong>[3<a title="3" name="3"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdsadasdasdasd<br />
```

it goes way up to hundreds

Comment: Do You need to replace `strong` tag with current number of replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$output = preg_replace('~^<strong>\[(\d+)<.*?<br\s*/>~', '$1. ', $input);
```

**explanation:**

```
~             : regex delimiter
  ^           : start of line
  <strong>    : <strong> as is
  \[          : an open square bracket
  (\d+)       : capture one or more digits
  <.*?        : > followed by any number of any char
  <br\s*/>    : <br/> or <br />
~
```

And replace all that match by the first captured group (ie. the digits) followed by a dot and a space.

**Edit according to comments:**

```
$input = '<strong>[1<a title="1" name="1"></a>]</strong><br /> Lorem ipsum 12345<br /> <strong>[2<a title="2" name="2"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdasd<br /> <strong>[3<a title="3" name="3"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdsadasdasdasd<br />';
$output = preg_replace('~\s*<strong>\[(\d+)<.*?<br\s*/>(.*?)(?:<br />|$)~', "$1. $2\n", $input);
echo $output,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
1.  Lorem ipsum 12345
2.  lorem ipsum asdasd
3.  lorem ipsum asdsadasdasdasd
```

Comment: hi, the output is same as $input value

Comment: the $output is same as $input, no changes is being made, i am doing something wrong? you need the text that im having?

Comment: @cicakman: Could you show us some sample input lines? I tested my answer and it worked fine.

Comment: `<strong>[1<a title="1" name="1"></a>]</strong><br /> Lorem ipsum 12345<br /> <strong>[2<a title="2" name="2"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdasd<br /> <strong>[3<a title="3" name="3"></a>]</strong><br /> lorem ipsum asdsadasdasdasd<br />` it goes way up until few hundreds

Comment: Are they all on same line ot separated by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use [preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and create a function to increment a variable and substitute the `*` with the current value of that variable (though I think you may have to use a global variable for this, which is generally considered bad practice).

Outside of that, I think you'd have to do it iteratively (i.e. in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

```
$x=1;
$result = preg_replace_callback (
'%<strong(.*?)strong><br.?/>.?(.*?)\r\n%sim'
, create_function(
          '$matches,$x',
          'return $x++.$matches[1];'
), $input );
```

Something like this

Comment: echo $result produce same as $input